# Why the Insights data have 7 days delay?

Tags: facebook-fql, delay, facebook-insights

I noticed that the data I got either from FQL insights table or the Insights tab of my app's management site has 7 days delay. Days ago the delay is about 2 days.

For example:
Assuming today is 2012-8-27,

```
SELECT metric, value 
FROM insights 
WHERE object_id=297730130255615 
AND metric='application_active_users' 
AND end_time=end_time_date('2012-08-21') 
AND period=period('day')
```

I get no data. I can get data from 8-20 and before.

Is there any way I can get more recent Insights data? My project can't afford such a slow turnaround time.

Answer (score 0):

Is this still an issue ? I was able to run the query you pasted and get back results.